# Promise Chaining / Cascading to RxJS angular 1 to angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I'm currently trying to convert some good old $http Promises into rxJs observables in angular2.

A very simple example of something I used to do frequently in angular 1:

```
// Some Factory in Angular 1
var somethings = [];
var service = {
    all: all
};
return service;

function all() {
    return $http
        .get('api/somethings')
        .then(function(response) {
            somethings = parseSomethings(response.data);
            return somethings;
        });
}

// Some Controller in Angular 1
var vm = this;
vm.somethings = [];
vm.loading = true;

loadThings();

function loadThings() {
    SomeFactory
        .all()
        .then(function(somethings) {
            vm.somethings = somethings;
        })
        .finally(function() {
            vm.loading = false;
        })
}
```

Now I can achieve something similar with angular2 using RxJs Observable and Subject. But I am unsure on how to return 'completion hooks'  down to the caller. (E.g.: The loading in the angular1 controller)

What I tried with for angular2 is something similar:

```
// Some Service in Angular 2
export class SomeService {
    private _somethings$: Subject<Something[]>;
    private dataStore: {
        somethings: Something[]
    };

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    get _somethings$() : Observable<Something[]> {
        return this._somethings$.asObservable();
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.http
            .get(`api/somethings`)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.dataStore.somethings = parseSomethings(response.data);
                    this._somethings$.next(this.dataStore.somethings);
                }
            );
    }
}

//Some Component in Angular 2
export class SomeComponent() {

    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.someService.loadAll();
        this.somethings = this.someService.somethings$;
    }
}
```

**Note**

I used a Subject / Observable here so that when I create / update / remove 'something' I can call .next to notify the subscribers.

E.g.:

```
create(something: Something) : Observable<Something>{
    return this.http.post(`api/somethings`, JSON.stringify(something))
        .map(response => response.json())
        .do(
            something => {
                this.dataStore.somethings.push(something);
                this._somethings$.next(this.dataStore.somethings); //Notify the subscribers
            }
        );
}
```

**Note**

Here I used .do in the method and when calling the method in a 'form component' I subscribe just to get completion handler:

```
this.someService.create(something).subscribe(
(ok) => ...
(error) => ...
() => stop loading indicator
)
```

**Questions**

- How can we pass down a completion-hook to callers (e.g. *angular 1 controller*) in angular 2 with RxJs
- What alternative paths do exist to achieve similar behaviour ?

Comment: Hey Im not quite familiar with AngularJS. But from my understanding you want to know when the `get` function is finished to set the `loading` to false? In that case, move the `subscribe` block in your service to your component and set the `loading` flag there.

Comment: Ok, should I unsubscribe aswel in the component (Lets say after calling create.subscribe() on a button click)

Comment: Nope, for `http.get` and `http.post` they will be completed once the response is returned so you don't need to `unsubscribe` them.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

Your last code example is fine. Just use `map()` instead of `subscribe()` and subscribe at call site.

You can use

```
return http.post(...).toPromise(val => ...))
```

or

```
return http.post(...).map(...).toPromise(val => ...))
```

to get the same behavior as in Angular where you can chain subsequent calls with `.then(...)`

Comment: I was thinking about using map aswel. Would .do be fine for this aswel ?

Comment: The value returned by `map()` is forwarded to the subscriber. If you don't want to modify the value but only cause some side-effects for each event, then `do()` is fine as well.

Comment: Can I assume that multiple .map calls will just `cascade` as .then would ?

Comment: Exactly. You can cascade all kinds of operators, also the same multiple times. Just `subscribe()` can be done only once at the end.